# Remove iTunes offline synced cache of movies

Tags: itunes, ipad

When I connect my iPad and want to add new, or remove old movies/videos, this is what I see in the Movies section:

[image]

I removed it from the iPad manually, then also from PC later. Now there should be just 2 movies, not 122. How to clear that cache or whatever is it? It is really annoying to list through 122 items to find just few. Not talking about warnings "Some of the items in the iTunes library, including XYZ, were not copied to the iPad XYZ because they could not be found".

Comment: When you go to the Movies section of iTunes, what do you see?

Comment: What section you mean? https://prnt.sc/gw6miq

Comment: I mean of your iTunes library. Leave the iPad section and navigate to Movies (as opposed to Music, Podcasts, Audiobooks, etc).

Comment: Oh I see now (I don't use iTunes a lot), there I was able to remove old movies, thanks. It would be much easier if it was managed by itself.

Comment: It **is** managed by itself - it just gets confused if you throw things away from the Finder that iTunes still thinks should be there.

Comment: How can I remove any file without appearing it in there again? I'm little confused now :)

Comment: Right click in iTunes > Delete from Library. It will ask if you want to keep the file itself [but remove any reference to it from iTunes] or throw it in the Trash.